# A student walks in to class to discover they had forgotten to study for a quiz. The quiz has 10 True-False questions

Tags: probability

Part a) is getting a passing grade of 60% with random guessing. Chance of 6 correct [(1/2)^10]*[10!/(4!)(6!)]=0.205078125 + 7 correct + 8 correct + 9 correct + 10 correct to get a 37.69% chance.

Part b) is they're confident that 3 are correct, and what is the probability that they get a 70%.  Since they already know 3 I figured I would only need the prob of 4 correct and the problem deals with only 7 questions now and that should give me the answer. [(1/2)^7]*[7!/(3!)(4!)] = 0.273438 for a 27% chance.

However part C is confusing me.  " How many questions does the student need to be correctly confident in to create a 90% or higher chance of getting a 70% on the quiz.

How do I go about part C?

Comment: This tutorial explains how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: How many questions can be unsure on to have a 90% chance of getting 7 questions right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the student will earn a grade of at least $70\%$ if the student knows how to answer at least seven questions correctly.

If the student only knows how to answer six of the questions correctly, the student will earn a mark of at least $70\%$ unless the student answers all of the remaining questions incorrectly.  Subtract that probability from $1$.  If that probability is at least $0.9$, then the student can be at least $90\%$ confident of earning a mark of at least $70\%$.

If that is the case, you need to check what happens if the student only knows how to answer five questions correctly.  The student will earn a mark of at least $70\%$ unless the student answers all of the remaining questions incorrectly or answers only one of them correctly.  Subtract that probability from $1$. If that probability is at least $0.9$, then the student can be at least $90\%$ confident of earning a mark of at least $70\%$.

Iterate as necessary.

Comment: Would I use 7 questions as the sample space?  Are you saying to start with 1 -  [(1/2)^7]*[7!/(4!)(6!)] = ?? ( which would be 1 - (6 correct)) and see if that is at least 0.9? Math is my weakness looking for a little direction.

Comment: If a student knows how to answer six questions, there are four remaining questions on which the student must guess.  Consequently, the student will earn a mark of at least $70\%$ unless he or she does not know how to answer all four of the remaining questions.  The probability of that happening is $1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 = 15/16 = 0.9375$.  Therefore, knowing six questions is sufficient.

Comment: If the student only knows how to answer five questions, there are five questions remaining on which the student must guess.  The student will earn a mark of at least $70\%$ unless he or she only answers at most one of those questions correctly.  You must subtract the probability that the student only answers $0$ or $1$ of those five questions correctly from $1$ to see if that number is larger than $1$.  If not, you may conclude that the student must know how to answer at least six questions.

Comment: That makes perfect sense thank you soooo much!  Also thank you for the Mathjax link.  I wasn't aware of some of that and wondered how some did that.  I'll study it for my next question.